# how to combine 2 file text with join line in ruby

Tags: ruby

Please help me how to do with this code. and what should i do with that code:

```
file1.txt       file2.txt
  aaa             111
  bbb             222
  ccc             333
  ddd             444
```

and the result just show like this

```
  aaa
  bbb
  ccc
  ddd
  111
  222
  333
  444
```

but what i want is

```
aaa|111
bbb|222
ccc|333
ddd|444
```

Here is my code

```
f1 = File.readlines('./file1.txt')
f2 = File.readlines('./file2.txt')

File.open('result.txt', 'w') do |output_file|
  f1.each_with_index do |elem, i|
    output_file.puts "#{elem} #{f2[i]}"
  end
end
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your code? Do you get an error or unexpected result?

Comment: the result that i got is  
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
111
222
333
444

Comment: it's not wjhat i want

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the wrong result?

Comment: i already change the question thank u  for helping me

Comment: Just gave it a try and couldn't reproduce your result. I'm getting alternating lines in the result, i.e. `aaa` on the 1st line, `111` on the 2nd, `bbb` on the 3rd and so on.

Comment: yeah that correct

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating on one array and looking up the second array by index, it is more elegant to [zip](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) the two arrays together. `puts` will, given an array, output each element in a separate row.

```
f1 = File.readlines('file1.txt', chomp: true)
f2 = File.readlines('file2.txt', chomp: true)

lines = f1.zip(f2).map { |items| items.join('|') }
puts lines
```

Or, using the new shorthand syntax, you could even say

```
lines = f1.zip(f2).map { _1.join('|') }
```

Answer (score 1):

*.map(&:chomp)*

```
f1 = File.readlines('./file1.txt').map(&:chomp)
f2 = File.readlines('./file2.txt').map(&:chomp)

File.open('result.txt', 'w') do |output_file|
  f1.each_with_index do |elem, i|
    output_file.puts "#{elem} #{f2[i]}"
  end
end
```

Result

```
aaa 111
bbb 222
ccc 333
ddd 444
```

Comment: There's also `File.readlines('./file1.txt', chomp: true)`

Comment: thank it's working by just add  File.readlines('./file1.txt', chomp: true) and File.readlines('./file2.txt', chomp: true)